# Git IntelliJ "Authentication Failed”

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I clone project with git. When I trying push/pull etc. using IntelliJ, I`ve got error "Authentication Failed". But when I use git commands in the console everything is okey and I can push, pull etc. I don't know what is the problem in IntelliJ. I tried delete and add again git in Settings, but it's not work.

Comment: Try setting credentials: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same issue. 
Go to **File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> Check "Use credential helper"**.
[image]

Comment: Did not work for me either, authentication succeeds if using git from the command line though, and `id_rsa` is in the `.ssh` folder too.

Comment: Didnt work for me either.

Comment: I had this one but totally forgot how to do it on the new machine.  Somehow, import settings from old one doesn't work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

File - Invalidate Caches / Restart - Invalidate and Restart) worked for me.