# "fatal: Authentication failed" with git-credential-manager

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, git-credential-manager

I'm using Azure DevOps for the first time to host my next project. When I created an empty project on Azure Devops, I tried to clone it. While attempting to clone, it asked me for my password. I entered it and it says I have a wrong password but I know I'm typing my password correctly.

I then installed **git-credential-manager** for max/linux onto my mac. I tried to do a `git pull` from the remote origin, but it just prompted for a password like the first time and failed.

I also tried to use the "Create git credentials" feature on Azure Devops, in which I can specify a new password. That failed as well with the same error.

I submitted a GitHub issue on their repository [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux/issues/104). Is there no way for me to clone my project? The url for my repository is in the form of `https://yousefshanawany@dev.azure.com/...`.

Update: I tried this on my Windows machine and it gave me a popup to login and it worked fine.

Comment: Please check this link you will get the clear idea about git authentication - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69556615/3660648

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure your git credential helper is declared to your local Git:

```
git config credential.helper
```

If the output is empty, type:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
```

Then try again.

However, the [OP AskYous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1404347/askyous) correctly pinpoint another issue [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661818/fatal-authentication-failed/53664088?noredirect=1#comment94211590_53664088):

> Can I tell it what my username is?
> I think my username is my email address, because I use my organization account to sign in.

In that case, the URL would be:

```
https://me%40email.com@dev.azure.com/yousefshanawany/<repo-name>/
```

Note the `@` of the email must be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).

---

Note that [using a PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) is an alternative mentioned [by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55317338/6309), and mandatory if [you have 2FA activated](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-two-factor-authentication).

---

Update June 2019: This question was referenced in [`microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux` issue 104](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux/issues/104), which just got closed with a comment from [John Briggs from Microsoft](https://github.com/jrbriggs):

> I'd recommend trying [GCM Core's macOS preview release](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core#download-and-install)

---

[Maksym Pecheniuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7179509/maksym-pecheniuk) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661818/fatal-authentication-failed/53664088#comment110563116_53664088):

> solution for IntelliJ Idea: "[Git IntelliJ "Authentication Failed”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62518658/6309)"

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but received the same response: https://i.imgur.com/BJuumPw.png

Comment: @AskYous What does `git remote -v` returns?

Comment: The URL seems strange: it should be `https://<you>@dev.azure.com/<you>/yourRepo`: I am not familiar with the `_git/xxx` part.

Comment: I tried the old URL on my windows machine and it worked fine. Got the UI login screen. I tried the new URL on my mac and it says: `Cloning into '<repo-name>'... fatal: repository https://yousefshanawany@dev.azure.com/yousefshanawany/<repo-name>/' not found`

Comment: @AskYous Is it possible to try with an URL *without* a trailing slash?

Comment: Can I tell it what my username is? I think my username is my email address because I use my organization account to sign in.

Comment: @AskYous If it is, don't forget to percent-encode the `@` (`%40`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters)

Comment: solution for IntelliJ Idea - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62518658/7179509

Answer (score 10):

What solved my issue was:

1. Create the repository from https://dev.azure.com/
2. From the repository view, create your credentials with `name` and `password`
   [image]
3. Now in the console you can clone your repository by changing the url that azure provides you initialy as

`git clone https://<companyname>@dev.azure.com/<companyname>/<project name>/_git/<repository name>`

to

`git clone https://<your credentials name>@dev.azure.com/<companyname>/<project name/_git/<repository name>`

now it will ask you for a password. You must use the one you provided when you created the credentials.

Answer (score 6):

The same error (Windows, Git Bash command line). Using https (not ssh) which should prompt for login credentials but instead errors:

```
$ git pull origin master
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/frmbelz/my_git_project.git'
```

```
$ git config -l
...
credential.helper=manager
...

$ git config --global --unset credential.helper
$ git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

`git pull` now prompted for username/password prompts.

Comment: For me `credential.helper` was `manager-core`, but simply `git config --global --unset credential.helper` and then reissuing the failed git command helped.

Answer (score 3):

A solution I found is to use a personal access token (PAT). It's located in the "clone" tab. It worked very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can reconfigure Git Credential Manager by running:

```
git credential-manager-core configure
```

Result:

> Configuring component 'Git Credential Manager'...
>
> Configuring component 'Azure Repos provider'...

Comment: somehow this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I added sudo to my git push command and i was prompted to enter my github credentials and it worked

```
sudo git push
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I found that I had to use the Git-Credential-Manager-Core utility:

https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core

Answer (score -1):

Right so my colleague and I were having the same trouble (didn't have this issue on windows, only on mac) and the above solution worked for him and didn't work for me. I had to create a Personal Access Token (PAT) via this guide [Authenticate Access With Personal Access Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts).

Then in iTerm:
git clone https://octavialo%40organizationname:abcBFJreallylongtokenstringGHYKLjjsjks@dev.azure.com/organizationname/reponame

%40 is a stand in for the @ sign. I sign in to azure with octavialo@organizationname.com

I also tried with this, where foobar was the name I gave the token:
git clone https://foobar:abcBFJreallylongtokenstringGHYKLjjsjks@dev.azure.com/organizationname/

I think the issue could have been with my password which had special characters.